# Template ToString function that works with different character encoding

Tags: c++

I've written an INI class that loads/saves/creates an INI data format, however right now it only works with ascii characters, and I would like to expand it to work with any type of character encoding, so besides char, wchar_t.  To do this, I have to setup various string functions for doing the parsing; I have some setup, however I need to rewrite them to work with any type of basic_string.

So, as to my question, I want a ToString function that will work with any type of character encoding, how do I do this?

I have the following two functions:

```
template <typename T>
static string toStr(const T& val)
{
    stringstream out;
    out << val;
    return out.str();
}

template <typename T>
static wstring toWStr(const T& val)
{
    wstringstream out;
    out << val;
    return out.str();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I originally posted this question I was close to the answer, but made a careless mistake, and thus have solved my own question while I was still typing it.  So for those of you who want a generic toString function that works for a variety of string encodings, here you go:

```
template<typename CharType, typename T>
static basic_string<CharType, char_traits<CharType>, allocator<CharType>> toString(const T& val)
{
    basic_stringstream<CharType> out;
    out << val;
    return out.str();
}
```

Comment: Good work! However, I'd recommend using the original functions. It's more comfortable to use properly named functions, than fiddle with template parameters, e.g. `toString<wchar_t>(123)`. It just looks better. Unless you need the compile-time polymorphism.

Comment: @Stefan It's just that for my INI system you can specify the encoding, and when I get around to writing my own JSON parser, I'll also allow you to specify the encoding using templates.  So unless there's a better option, I think this is the only way I can do this, yes?

Comment: Pretty much yes. If you have a class e.g. `template <typename CharType> class IniFile;` and you want to call from it a proper toString() overload, then your way is the right way. That's what I meant by compile-time polymorphism.